# Permalink structure wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, permalinks

I want send the user to go to a different template if a variable is on the end of a post name.  So I would want http://www.google.com/%category%/%postname%/google/ pass in the variable google and change the page and http://www.google.com/%category%/%postname%/yahoo/ pass in the variable yahoo.  I know this has been done with page templates and variables but I don't know if it's been done the a postname end.